# Can't select and type in Search (Windows 10, 1909)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-v1909

After recent update to Windows 10 (v 1909), I can no longer type in windows explorer Search. 
When I mouseover  and click in, and try to type in anything, it just doesn't do anything, still like this:

[image]

I've even tried to click at first in "address bar" and then click <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate in Search field and type anything, still doesn't work (when typing, just types 1 letter and disappears)

Comment: You are trying to search New Folder (your screenshot) and likely nothing there. Open Windows Explorer, navigate to some top folder (say in Documents), and then see "Search Documents" in the top right bar. Type a search term in there and see if Windows begins searching

Comment: @John Sorry no absolutely. there are files and also in any folder does same

Comment: I have no issue with Windows 10 V 1909 searching files. Make sure your system is fully updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in Windows 10, 1909.

Some suggest that killing and re-spawning the explorer pose a temporary fix.

Read about this bug  [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/file-explorer-search-not-working-in-windows-10/3c70ea75-79a8-4f3b-b10a-86be1f22931c)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about ctfmon.exe not working: restarting this program per Windows run solved the issue for me.

```
WinKey + r  "C:\Windows\system32\ctfmon.exe"  *Enter*
```

https://appuals.com/fix-windows-10-cant-type-in-search/